# How to change background image inside a div class without affecting child elements

Tags: html, css

How to make my button image change background color with a transparency at hover and without affecting the  title "Kids".

When I hover the image box, the  is also being affected, causing an extra layer of transparency.

```css
.kids {
  background-image: url(/kids_image.jpg);
}

div.kids :hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}
```

```html
<div class="kids">
    <a href="http://sampleurl.com">
        <div class="grid960">
            <h1>Kids</h1>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `div.kids:hover`. (Remove the space). You want the background image on `.kids`, right? If you want it on its direct child (and only on its direct child), use `div.kids > *:hover`.

Comment: You'll probably need to hard-code a background for the h1, for example `h1 {background-color: white;}`.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG images do not have transparency, so what you are seeing in your example is the image only, which covers up the `background-color` set on `:hover`.

You will need open the image in an editing application, remove the background, and resave as a PNG with transparency. Alternately you could make a second image with the alternate background colour baked in.